# Symmetry, change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

I am having trouble understanding a section in [these notes](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~francisv/publications/XXV-ICGTMP-Proceeding/dkdv.pdf). It is on page 3. Section 3 -- Discretization of the [Korteweg-de Vries equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Korteweg-deVriesEquation.html). I don't understand why $$V_4=x∂_x+3t∂_t-2u∂_u$$ generates a symmetry group of the KdV. I see that it generates the transformation
$$(x',t',u')= (x\exp(\epsilon), 3t\exp(\epsilon), -2u\exp(\epsilon))$$
So $u'_{t'}-6u'u'_{x'}+u'_{x'x'x'}=-{2\over 3}u_t-24\exp(\epsilon)uu_x-2\exp(-2\epsilon)u_{xxx}$ How does this vanish (so that we get symmetry) given that $u$ satisfies the KdV?

---

Is it possible that I have misunderstood something, such that from "I see that..." onwards I have been barking up the wrong tree?

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/s_/lgde.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation generated by $V_4$ is not the one you've written, but
$$
(x',t',u')=(x \exp(\epsilon), t \exp(3 \epsilon) , u \exp(-2\epsilon)).
$$
(You can tell right away that something is wrong with your transformation, since it doesn't reduce to the identity map when $\epsilon=0$.)

Comment: Ahhh!! Thank you, Hans!

Comment: You're welcome.